# Regex to exclude set of words with achieving this format

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

(I can't imagine how this question is off-topic, it is only asking about a regex just like a dozen questions on stackoverflow !!!!!!!!!)

In order to find a solution to the question [User-friendly URLs for user profiles in YaF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875717/user-friendly-urls-for-user-profiles-in-yaf)
one way of solving it is by finding a regex to capture anything else other than the predefined list of controllers,

So I need a regex to match this `/notAcontroller` where `notAcontroller` is not one of my predefined controllers like in this array `[index, home, profile]`

**Example:**

For these controllers `[index, home, profile]`

I need to match for strings like these: `/Joan`, `/abdelhady/photos`

but not these: `/profile/get/id/222`, `/index` or even `/`

Comment: What is the language? And what have you attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: PHP, & I'm trying to solve the problem I've listed before in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875717/user-friendly-urls-for-user-profiles-in-yaf

Comment: I can't imagine how this question is off-topic, it is only asking about a regex just like a DOZEN questions here on stackoverflow !!! anyway, I edited it to further explain my problem

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look ahead anchored to start:

```
^/(?!(index|home|profile)$).*
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/I3fl0txKUn)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It can exclude `/profile` which is desired, but it can't exclude `profile/get/id/222` or `/` as in the question

Comment: Sure it works. Click "live demo".

Comment: `^(\/(index|home|profile).*|\/$)` works like you want I think. http://rubular.com/r/OvwlJL3NnT

Comment: My previous comment is in your demo, the regex excluded `/index' which is right, but it fails to exclude other 2 which is needed also

Comment: @Christoph your regex is doing almost the exact opposite to what I want, I'm sorry if you found the question not clear enough, I'll try to enhance the question wording

Comment: where's your problem? `if(preg_match() === false)` ?!

Comment: Sorry, but I have to pass the regex to a routing rule as is, to be used by the rule